# Accuracy testing of forecasts

Tags: r, forecasting

I found a site which explains exactly what I need to do for my data however it isn't in R. Can anyone suggest how I could create this in R?

http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/three.htm

I need to find the MSE, MAE, MAPE, ME, MPE, SSE to test the accuracy of the forecasts and this page is the closest i have found to explain how to do it.

```
data<-c(79160.56266,91759.73029,91186.47551,106353.8192,70346.46525,80279.15139,82611.60076,131392.7209,93798.99391,105944.7752,103913.1296,154530.6937,110157.4025,117416.0942,127423.4206,156751.9979,120097.8068,121307.7534,115021.1187,150657.8258,113711.5282,115353.1395,112701.9846,154319.1785,116803.545,118352.535)
forecasts<-c(118082.3,157303.8,117938.7,122329.8) # found using arima
```

(if you mark this question down can you explain specifically why please)

Comment: I'm not a "down-voter" but it would be good to show your effort and code you've used. You are basically asking for someone do it for you based on what you'd like to get done. This is a strong indicator for getting down-voted. Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684479/explaining-the-forecasts-from-an-arima-model?rq=1)?

Comment: You should be able to find information on each of the listed statistics on Wikipedia - [MSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) for example. There should be base R functions to calculate most (if not all) of these values, or you could look into packages like [lmtest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmtest/lmtest.pdf). At the very least, they are fairly trivial computations so you could easily write you own functions if you had to.

Comment: @PauloCardoso i wasn't asking for someone to do it for me, only to suggest how to do it in the way the page said. Everytime i put up code people complain that it is too long or irrelevant. I am using different forecasting methods which is also why i didnt put in a code. yeah i looked at that but it still doesnt explain what i need

Comment: Rob Hyndman's [text on forecasting](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/7) uses R for all the examples. It's freely available online.

Comment: @nrussell i have looked on wikipedia ect for ways to do it. The page i put in my question seems to test the accuracy of the in-sample and i think also of the out-of-sample which is exactly what i need to do...but i cant figure out how to a)find these samples in my data and b)understand how to code it properly. i have been working on this for about 5 hours now :/

Comment: @eipi10 i have printed out the whole of this already but im still not sure its giving me exactly what i want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a few examples to get you started, using the data set `UKNonDurables` from the package `AER`. This package accompanies the book [Applied Econometrics with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387773169), which is a pretty good introductory applied econometrics book, especially for people without a solid background in programming.

```
library(forecast)
library(AER) 
##
data("UKNonDurables")
## alias for convenience
Data <- UKNonDurables
## split data into testing and training
train <- window(
  Data,
  end=c(1975,4))
test <- window(
  Data,
  start=c(1976,1))
## fit a model on training data
aaFit <- auto.arima(
  train)
## forcast training model over
## the testing period
aaPred <- forecast(
  aaFit,
  h=length(test))
##
> plot(aaPred)
```

[image]

```
## extract point forecasts
yHat <- aaPred$mean
## a few functions:
## mean squared (prediction) error
MSE <- function(y,yhat)
{
  mean((y-yhat)**2)
}
## mean absolute (prediction) error
MAE <- function(y,yhat)
{
  mean(abs(y-yhat))
}
## mean absolute percentage (prediction) error
MAPE <- function(y,yhat,percent=TRUE)
{
  if(percent){
    100*mean(abs( (y-yhat)/y ))
  } else {
    mean(abs( (y-yhat)/y ))
  }
}
##
> MSE(test,yHat)
[1] 9646434
> MAE(test,yHat)
[1] 1948.803
> MAPE(test,yHat)
[1] 3.769978
```

So like I said, some or all of the above functions probably exist in base R or within external packages, but they are typically simple formulas that are trivial to implement. Try to work off these and / or adapt them to better suit your needs.

**Edit:** 
As Mr. Hyndman pointed out below, his package `forecast` includes the function `accuracy`, which provides a very convenient way of summarizing GOF measures of time series models. Using the same data from above, you can easily assess the fit of a `forecast` object over the training and testing periods:

```
> round(accuracy(aaPred,Data),3)
                   ME     RMSE      MAE   MPE  MAPE  MASE  ACF1 Theil's U
Training set    2.961  372.104  277.728 0.001 0.809 0.337 0.053        NA
Test set     1761.016 3105.871 1948.803 3.312 3.770 2.364 0.849     1.004
```

(where `round(...,3)` was used just so that the output would fit nicely in this post). Or, if you want to examine these measures for only the forecast period, you can call something like this:

```
> accuracy(yHat,test)
               ME     RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE      ACF1 Theil's U
Test set 1761.016 3105.871 1948.803 3.312358 3.769978 0.8485389  1.004442
```

Comment: thankyou :) i dont suppose you know how is the best way to interperet the results? like if its best to have MAPE small or large, or whether comparing MSE and MAE to other models its better for them to be bigger or smaller?

Comment: Generally speaking you want all of these values to be as small as possible (since they represent the amount of difference between observed values and what your model predicted). However, like most questions about statistical inference, there isn't a cut-and-dry approach to interpreting goodness of fit values, so you will have to do a fair amount of reading on the subject. That website you linked is a good source, and I would recommend browsing through questions on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) - perhaps asking this question on that site if you don't find answers elsewhere.

Comment: The `accuracy` function from the `forecast` package does it all for you.

Comment: @RobHyndman Thank you for pointing that out (and for contributing such a great package).